# How do I display only one result (the highest) with SQL query? (Beginner)

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, max

I need help making the following query only display one result, the one with the `MAX Procurement Rate`.

Currently the query works, but displays all results not just the one with the output of the `MAX` function

```
SELECT SalesPeople.SalesPersonID, FirstName, LastName, Region, SalesRevenueYear1, ProcurementCost
FROM ProductRevenueAndCosts 
INNER JOIN SalesPeople 
    ON ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID = SalesPeople.SalesPersonID
WHERE SalesPeople.Region = 'Central' AND (
    SELECT MAX (ProcurementCost)
    FROM ProductRevenueAndCosts
    WHERE SalesPeople.Region = 'Central'
)
```

Comment: I don't think that query does what you think it does. You're not comparing the result of the inner query to anything.

Comment: Normally if you want one record, you'd use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`. If you want one record for each value in some condition, you'd use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I attempted to simplify the query, removing the inner query, and using MAX in conjunction with GROUP BY, but the end result is the same. I am new to this, perhaps I am missing something obvious, I am just trying to retrieve only the revenue, cost and salesperson details for the product with the highest procurement rate within a certain region, in this case 'central', hence my attempt to use MAX alongside defining the central region. I apologise if I am making an obvious mistake, I am using SQL for the first time today.

Comment: The query is invalid unless ProcurementCost is a boolean which doesn't seem likely. You probably want `AND ProcurementCost = (SELECT MAX(ProcurementCost) ...)`. And which DBMS are you using? You tagged two different ones, MySQL and MS Access. For which of the two do you want a solution?

Comment: MS Access, my apologies I should have made that clear, I wasn't aware that there was a difference. I'm new to this as of today, trying my best to come to grips with it but finding it incredibly complex as of right now.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and whilst it did return the desired result of a single row, all fields were blank

Answer (score 1):

If you add a LIMIT 1 clause at the end of your SQL, then only the first record will be shown. If you add an ORDER BY `column_name`, then the results will be ordered by that column. Using these two together is a quick way to get the max or min without having to worry about aggregate functions.
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_limit.asp
Otherwise, you can try aggregating the results with a max function:
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_min_max.asp

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to correlate the subquery to outer query. Be sure to use aliases between same named columns and exercise good practice in qualifying all columns with table names or aliases especially in `JOIN` queries:

```sql
SELECT sp.SalesPersonID, sp.FirstName, sp.LastName, sp.Region, sp.SalesRevenueYear1, 
       prc.ProcurementCost
FROM ProductRevenueAndCosts prc
INNER JOIN SalesPeople sp
    ON prc.SalesPersonID = prc.SalesPersonID
WHERE sp.Region = 'Central' 
  AND prc.ProcurementCost = (                   -- CORRELATE OUTER QUERY WITH SUBQUERY
    SELECT MAX(ProcurementCost)
    FROM ProductRevenueAndCosts
)
```

<sup>Note: If running in MS Access, remove the comment</sup>